# Unreadable desktop text with theme

Tags: unity, gnome, themes, gtk

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS with unity user interface

```
kernel 4.15.18-041518-generic
gtk amd64 version 3.22
```

I installed two themes from b00merang: https://b00merang.weebly.com/windows-10.html
-Windows-10 black theme and
-Windows-10 light theme

I have no problem with black theme.
With white theme however, the text of desktop shortcuts/files is unreadable.

Here an example image showing with black theme:

[image: Windows10 dark theme]

Here is the problem with white theme:

[image: Windows10 light theme]

Both themes were put in `~/.themes/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is only for the mentioned theme in the question, i.e "Windows-10-master" Theme.

in this particular theme, to change the text color of folders on Desktop.

i have saved my themes in `/usr/share/themes/` you need to replace `/usr/share/themes` with `~/.themes` in the below example as you saved your themes in `~/.themes/`

I have created a `nautilus.css` file in the folder
 `/usr/share/themes/Windows-10-master/gtk-3.20/apps`

made the content in this file as below

```
.nautilus-desktop.nautilus-canvas-item {
    color: blue; # <--------- here in the place of "blue" you can put any valid color you want
}
```

Save the file & Close.

now, Open the file `gtk.css` in the folder`/usr/share/themes/Windows-10-master/gtk-3.20/`

add the below line at the end,
`@import url("apps/nautilus.css");`

after adding this line, last 3 lines should look like this.

```
@import url("gtk-contained.css");
@import url("apps/gnome-terminal.css");
@import url("apps/nautilus.css");
```

Save the file & Close.

Reboot to see the change.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is with the text colour of the theme.

You can change this quite easily, since GTK+ themes (as of GTK+ 3) are simply CSS (Cascading Style Sheets).

You can change the colour to

```
#FFFFFF;
```

as opposed to

```
@desktop_item_fg;
```

in this section:

```
.caja-desktop,
.nemo-desktop.nemo-canvas-item,
.nautilus-desktop.nautilus-canvas-item {
    color: @desktop_item_fg;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px @desktop_item_text_shadow;
}
```

Or change the value of the variable:

```
@define-color fg_color
```

You might also want to consider a more up to date theme. You can find several of the same kind on [gnome-look.org](http://gnome-look.org).

Comment: There is no desktop.css file into the app folder actually, can you please have a look at this?

Comment: @ExtrUnsk if this answer didn't solve your question, you shouldn't mark it as solved with the "tick." I haven't (yet) downloaded the theme to check it for myself, but see if the updated answer works for you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried changing desktop_item_fg to #ffffff in gtk.css and every other css file including it but it did not work. Same for second option. The only thing that made text color to change was setting @define-color theme_fg_color #ffffff in the gtk.css file BUT all the text in nautilus also went to white so this is not an option.

Comment: If you have time to download the theme to check that would be great, otherwise I will just try to find a similar theme. Please let me know!

Comment: @ExtrUnsk that's probably your best option, short of filing a bug report. I don't think I would be able to get a much better result, and it would take a while digging around and playing with values to get it right otherwise. All the best!