# Changing Homescreen Icon Text Color

Tags: icons, themes

I hope all is well. I recently joined the linux community and have been having trouble with one thing specifically; the home screen icon text color. Every file I have on the home screen has dark grey text below it, and while I could change the home screen I'd rather just make the text white. I'm on the latest LTS version of Ubuntu, but any advice would be welcome!

Many thanks.
Nate

Comment: Suggest you take a look at https://vitux.com/how-to-customize-theme-on-ubuntu/ for the answrs I find here are years old.

Comment: @Nate S0 y0ur 0S is Ubuntu 18.04?? And Y0u mean Changing the font c0l0r 0f Desktop Icons??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unreadable desktop text with theme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083329/unreadable-desktop-text-with-theme)